# Selecting from 2 tables in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that I'm querying for value 43 in the second field and I return the value of the third field

```
SELECT t1_field3 FROM table1 WHERE t1_field2=43

this returns 19, 39,73 

t1_id    t1_field2    t1_field3
-----    ---------    ---------
1           43        19////            
2           43        39////             
3           43        73////
4           73        43
5           13        40
```

Then I separately query a second table for additional information

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE t2_id=t1_field3

t2_id    t2_field2    t2_field3
-----    ---------    ---------
19       value19.2    value19.3
39       value39.2    value39.3
73       value73.2    value73.3
```

Is there a way I could combine both table1 and table2 in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table2 
where t2_id in (select t1_field3 from table1 where t1_field2=43 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You're describing a JOIN. In this case you don't need to explicitly use the JOIN keyword though, you can just do this:

```
SELECT table1.t1_field3, table2.* FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.t1_field2=43 AND table2.t2_id = table1.t1_field3
```

It would probably be helpful to learn about the different types of joins at some point; Coding Horror has a [good post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) about it

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to express the join directly as well like so:

```
select table1.t1_field3, table2.* 
  from table1
  join table2 on table1.t1_field3 = table2.t2_id
 where table1.t1_field2 = 43;
```